# Let A ∈ R 5×5 with det(A) = −4. Find det(B)

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Photo of problem]

The answer is D and I have no idea why. Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: What is the "standard notation for elementary matrices discussed in class"?

Comment: http://linear.ups.edu/html/section-PDM.html

Comment: The standard notation is pretty much what Adriano listed below. He answered it perfectly so my question has been answered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing from your "standard notation", use the facts that:

- $\det(S_{ij}(c)) = 1$
- $\det(P_{ij}) = -1$
- $\det(D_i(c)) = c$
- $\det(MN) = \det M \cdot \det N$

This yields:
$$
(1)(-1)(\tfrac{1}{8})(-1)(4)(-1)(\det B) = -4 \iff \det B = 8
$$

Comment: What is $S_{ij}(c)$?

Comment: @achillehui: I'm guessing it's the elementary matrix corresponding to the row operation of "adding $c$ times row $i$ to row $j$".

Comment: I see, unlike other notations (P for parity, D for diagonal), it never occur to me $S$ can stand for row operation ;-p